Pspice - logic gates in series

I'm triying to simulate (PSPICE for Ti 2024) this circuit, but it doesn't work as expected. On the net /B there is a pulsed signal, after U20 I'm getting a signal around mVolt's. After U23/U21, both signals are always on HIGH.
My idea is add some delay, because in other net there is a single INV, so this circuits shall be slower.
I don't know what is happening; you can put gates in series.


Your Vcc for U20 and U21 is missing.


It's a typo. Also on U22/U23 does the same issue

@A.martinez Please show with your full and correct schematic used for the simulation.

Updated picture

@A.martinez Same issue as before, no Vcc for U20 and U21. Please provide an oscillogram with OE, A, Y and Vcc. Do you have a model for your CD74AC240? Any errors in the error log?

Hi winny, it has power supply, trust me. Anyway, U22/U23, does de SAME issue.
I added the oscillogram, you will see V(/A) it's the U22 input and its output.

No warnings durins simulation and the models comes from Pspice for Ti

@A.martinez Probe Vcc and OE as well.

VCC is 3.3 volts and OE is tied to GND.
